# Path Traversal issue while using dynamic data in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a path using dynamic data. it involves concatenating data to form path. Example shown below.

```
 <add key="ProjectPath" value="c:\SampleFiles\Projects" /> // from webconfig
     
 string project=gv_projects.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;  

 ViewState["ProjectFolder"]=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectPath"].ToString()+"//"+project;

 string oldfolder =ViewState["ProjectFolder"].ToString();
 Directory.Move(oldfolder, newfolder);
```

How do i resolve Path Traversal issue.

Comment: no idea what „Path Traversal issue“ means

Comment: What exactly is your ‘path traversal issue’?